# Getting '403 Forbidden' error when using headless chrome with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

When using regualr chromedriver, my tests run without any issues and I get the test results. When I am trying to launch headless chrome with python and selenium, I get a '403 Forbidden' error on the screenshot and `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` on the console. I passed all these arguments and still get the same result :

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I also tried the `from fake_headers import Headers` but the issue still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#try this 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
def web(url):
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080)) 
    display.start()
    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.chrome
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome (options = chrome_options)
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer for the question. I am thinking it is a UserAgent issue?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution which is similar to the first answer.
[The explanation for the issue can be found here.](https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/) This took care of the issue for me.

```
chrome_options = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Adding the user agent resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you had a "Useragent" problem but it is advisable to use display() for web pages that have anti-bot protection, although this solution is temporary.
My main language is Spanish